# How to dynamically update what is being appended using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append a box to a list. This box should have a heading which identifies it, but I am having trouble figuring out how to increment each heading by 1.

Currently, the boxes are being generated by this code when a button is clicked.

```
function createBoxYes(i) {
    var box = '<div class="panel-heading">Question 1</div>';
    $("#yesColumn").append(box);
}
```

However, I am trying to increment the Question number based on the input, `i`. It should equal `i + 1`. My first thought was to put an id on the div, but if I used `findElementById("question")`, then it would select all of the boxes, and I want to simply have each box generated to remain unchanged.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you.

```
function createBoxYes(i) {
   var box = '<div class="panel-heading">Question' + (i + 1) +'</div>';
    $("#yesColumn").append(box);
}
```

Just put i+1 in there.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this ll helps you:

```js
var questions = 1;
function createBoxYes() {
    var box = '<div class="panel-heading">Question ' + ++questions + '</div>';
    $("#yesColumn").append(box);
}
$('#addBox').bind('click', createBoxYes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="yesColumn" class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">Question 1</div>
</div>

<button id="addBox" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
```